# Jquery replace number in fixed location

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I am writing a function which is used to replace the class of div in certain conditions, for example,

1. **condition A** - the div class is e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7, I want to replace the 2 to 1, outcome should be like this - e_new_hazard_frame_1_1_4_7
2. **condition B** - the div class is the same with above, I want to replace the 1 to 4, outcome should be like this - e_new_hazard_frame_2_4_4_7
3. **condition C** - the div class is the same with above, I want to replace the 4 to 6, outcome should be like this - e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_6_7
4. **condition D** - the div class is the same with above, I want to replace the 7 to 3, outcome should be like this - e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_3

these 4 numbers might be the same, like 1_1_1_1, my demo coding is like
                 var str = 'e_new_hazard_frame_2_1';
                 str = str.replace(/_[_0-9]*)$/,'1');

it seems not correct can anyone teach me how to do it? thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a function to handle the numbers however you want?

[replace Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, offset, string){
  // p1-4 are your numbers 
  // (they are strings right now, sto make +p1 to convert them to int)
  p1= +p1 + 1;
  p2= +p2 + 1;
  p3= +p3 + 1;
  p4= +p4 + 1;

  // fixed a small bug here
  return ['', p1, p2, p3, p4].join('_');
};

var str = "asdasdasd_1_2_3_4";
str = str.replace(/_(\d)_(\d)_(\d)_(\d)/, replacer);
```

Comment: just fixed a small bug I had. Should work now. NOTE: it only works when all numbers are single digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.It may help you.

```
<div class="e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7">click to change value</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7").on('click',function(){
    change_class(7); //change the value from here i.e 2,4,1,7
});

function change_class(p)
{
    var number_change=p;
    switch (number_change)
    {
        case 2:
        var str='e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7';  
        str = str.replace(/[2]/g,'1');
        break;
        case 1:
        var str='e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7';  
        str = str.replace(/[1]/g,'4');
        break;
        case 4:
        var str='e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7';  
        str = str.replace(/[4]/g,'6');
        break;
        case 7:
        var str='e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7';  
        str = str.replace(/[7]/g,'3');
        break;    
    }
$(".e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7").html(str);
}
</script>
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In **PHP**

```
    echo str_replace("2","1","e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7");
```

For more reference visit [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Hope this will help you.

In **JavaScript**

```
 str.replace("e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_2_4","e_new_hazard_frame_1_1_2_4");
```

For more reference visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: He want to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all occurrence of 2 to 1 in str:

```
var str = 'e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_2_4'; 
str = str.replace(/2/g,'1');
```

To replace the class of your div:

```
var target_class = 'e_new_hazard_frame_2_1_4_7';
$('.'+target_class).removeClass(target_class).addClass(target_class.replace(/2/g,'1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be useful to you
    `str='e_new_hazard_frame_2_1';

```
if(conditin1) 
{
 pattern = /[2]/g;
 str = str.replace(pattern,'1');
}

if(conditin2)
{
pattern = /[1]/g;
str = str.replace(pattern,'4');
}

if(conditin3)
{ 
 pattern = /[4]/g;
 str = str.replace(pattern,'6');
}

if(conditin4)
{
 pattern = /[7]/g;
 str = str.replace(pattern,'3');
}`
```